# ConvNeXT hyperparameter tuning error (Optuna)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, valueerror, optuna

I am running a  model to classify a binary image dataset.
Where ResNet50v2 or InceptionV3 works fine but with ConVnextTiny I run into some issues.

It runs the first trail with Optuna but after that I receive the following error:

I receive a ValueError: No such layer: layer_normalization. Existing layers are: ['input_2', 'convnext_tiny_prestem_normalization', 'convnext_tiny_stem', 'convnext_tiny_stage_0_block_0_depthwise_conv',....

My code is bellow:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ConvNeXtTiny

def hp_fruits_ConvNeXtTiny(trail):

  # Initialize the base model. Set the input shape and remove the dense layers.
  ConvNeXtTiny_model = ConvNeXtTiny(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), 
                                  include_top = False, 
                                  weights = 'imagenet')

  # Freeze the weights of the layers.
  for layer in ConvNeXtTiny_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

  # Choose the last layer of your base model
  last_layer = ConvNeXtTiny_model.get_layer('layer_normalization')
  print('last layer output shape: ', last_layer.output_shape)
  last_output = last_layer.output


  # Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
  x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
  
  # Add a fully connected layer with 1,024 hidden units and ReLU activation
  hidden_layers = trail.suggest_int('hidden_layers', 1, 2)

  for i in range(hidden_layers):
    first_neuron = trail.suggest_categorical('first_neuron', [128, 256, 512])
    x = layers.Dense(first_neuron, activation='relu')(x)
    # Add dropout
    drop_out = trail.suggest_categorical('drop_out', [0, 0.3, 0.5])
    x = layers.Dropout(drop_out)(x)                  
  
  # Add a final sigmoid layer for binary classification
  x = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)           

  # Append the dense network to the base model
  model = Model(ConvNeXtTiny_model.input, x) 

  # Set the optimizer and learning rate using Optuna suggestions
  optimizer_name = trail.suggest_categorical('optimizer', ['Adam', 'RMSprop', 'AdamW'])
  learning_rate = trail.suggest_float('lr', 1e-5, 1e-2, log=True)

  if optimizer_name == 'Adam':
      optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
  elif optimizer_name == 'RMSprop':
      optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)
  elif optimizer_name == 'AdamW':
      optimizer = AdamW(learning_rate=learning_rate)

  # Compile the model with binary cross-entropy loss and accuracy metric
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                metrics = ['accuracy', Recall(), Precision()])
  
  # Train the model with early stopping
  early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
  model.fit(train, validation_data=val, class_weight=class_weights, epochs = 100, callbacks=[early_stop],
            max_queue_size=40, workers=4, use_multiprocessing=True)
  
  # Evaluate the model on the validation set
  y_pred_val = model.predict(val)
  y_pred_val = np.round(y_pred_val)

  f1score_macro = f1_score(val.labels, y_pred_val, average = 'micro')
  print(f1score_macro)
  
  return f1score_macro

if __name__ == "__main__":
    warnings.warn(
        "Recent Keras release (2.4.0) simply redirects all APIs "
        "in the standalone keras package to point to tf.keras. "
        "There is now only one Keras: tf.keras. "
        "There may be some breaking changes for some workflows by upgrading to keras 2.4.0. "
        "Test before upgrading. "
        "REF:https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.4.0"
    )
    study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
    study.optimize(hp_fruits_ConvNeXtTiny, n_trials=10)

    print("Number of finished trials: {}".format(len(study.trials)))

    print("Best trial:")
    trial = study.best_trial

    print("  Value: {}".format(trial.value))

    print("  Params: ")
    for key, value in trial.params.items():
        print("    {}: {}".format(key, value))
```

I would like to know if anyone knows the solution or has had this problem before? Hopefully someone can help me.